# Java - RegEx pattern that consists of LDAP attributes

Tags: java, regex, attributes, ldap

Is there a way to use LDAP attributes stored in Strings as the RegEx pattern?

I am thinking something like this:

```
PASSWORD_WITH_LDAP_ATTRIBUTE = Pattern.compile(userid + "|" + ssn + "|" + bdate + "|" + empNo + "|" + telNo);
```

I already tried this one out. In any string that I input, the regex always finds a match even though its not a clear match.

Is this possible or am I venturing to the impossible?

Here is the whole method:

```
private static Pattern PASSWORD_WITH_LDAP_ATTRIBUTE = null;


private boolean checkForLdapAttributes(final String newPassword) throws LDAPException{
    LoggingEnt loggingEnt = new LoggingEnt();
    String userid = loggingEnt.getUseridCode();
    String ssn = loggingEnt.getSocialSecurityNumber();
    String bdate = loggingEnt.getBirthDate();
    String empNo = loggingEnt.getEmployeeNumber();
    String telNo = loggingEnt.getTelephoneNumber();     

    PASSWORD_WITH_LDAP_ATTRIBUTE = Pattern.compile(userid + "|" + ssn + "|" + bdate + "|" + empNo + "|" + telNo);
    matcher = PASSWORD_WITH_LDAP_ATTRIBUTE.matcher(newPassword);

    if(PASSWORD_WITH_LDAP_ATTRIBUTE.matcher(newPassword).find()){
        isPasswordAccepted = false;
        loggingEnt.setMsg1("You cannot use any of your Username, Social Security No., Birthdate, Employee No., and Telephone No. as password.");
        throw new LDAPException("Invalid password combination for " + userid, LDAPException.INVALID_CREDENTIALS);
    } else {
        loggingEnt.setMsg1("Password accepted.");
        isPasswordAccepted = true;
    }

    return matcher.matches();
}
```

Comment: What input, Regex and match did you use and get?

Comment: The input was `Pasw70rd12`. The regex is supposed to be dynamic to what ever the attribute's value is in accordance to the user

Comment: That is one input, you have at least 5 variables which you are inputting as the regex, without knowing what these are it'll be hard for anyone to help. If you post your code on how you match, what the string variables used as input are and your resulting match someone will be able to provide help sooner. I think what you are trying to acheive is possible just more details are needed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're doing this wrong. You're not supposed to match the password attribute yourself. You are supposed to attempt to 'bind' to LDAP specifying a username and password, and *it* will match the password for you. Or not.

In JNDI, 'bind' corresponds to `LdapContext.reconnect().`